# Is there a shortcut to wrap text as a code chunk in a RMarkdown file in RStudio?

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts, quarto

Any shortcut to transform text as a code block by selecting the text and pressing keys ?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to something like ["code snippets"](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets-in-the-RStudio-IDE) Which RStudio has a settings tab for

Comment: NO, I want to select the text, press keys (or press button on RStudio) and then the text must be inside a code chunk

Comment: You copy(ctrl+c) and then do keyboard shortcut to insert R chunk `Ctrl + Alt + I` on Windows, or `Cmd + Option + I` on macOS). and then do a paste(ctrl+v)

Comment: It's not direct enough, I want a solution tw moves : 1 ) select the text  2) press keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a package `{chunkthis}` which provides a Rstudio Addins `Chunk the code` to do this.

At first, install the package from GitHub using `install_github` which is a function from `{remotes}` package.

```
# install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("shafayetShafee/chunkthis")
```

Doing this will add the addin in Rstudio. Then, simply copy something then use that addin to paste wrapped in a R code-chunk fence. Or even you can add a keyboard shortcut for that addin.

To add a shortcut for Rstudio Addin, navigate to `Tools -> Addins -> Browse Addins -> keyboard Shortcuts...` and then add a key board shortcut for that addin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have just noted that the `remedy` add-in had a similar option called `Chunk`

Comment: But your solution is prettier